# java String.Format("%02d") produces strange unicode characters

Tags: java, unicode, printf, string-formatting

I'm doing exactly this:

```
    int level = ...;//some value from game
    Analytics.newDesignEvent(String.format("level_end:%02d:win", level));
```

And I've found that some devices send strings with unicode symbols such as "٠١":

**level_end:٠١:win**

I've tried to reproduce it in my environment, but String.format worked ok with any integer value.
May this be somehow caused by specific locales? Why else this can happen?

Updt2:
I didn't find any info whether string + int/float/etc. concantenation also take locale into consideration. Do smbd happen to know?

Comment: Why do you use `"foo:"+String.format("bar%x",data)` instead of `String.format("foo:bar%x,data)`?

Comment: Interesting. You can add an answer to your question and accept it.  It is fine to do so on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Pshemo it doesn't matter, strings without concantenation work the same

Comment: @MikeNakis yes, once I'll make sure it really was the root of an evil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java docs it is said:

> Number localization. Some conversions use localized decimal digits
>   rather than the usual ASCII digits. So formatting 123 with %d will
>   give 123 in English locales but ١٢٣ in appropriate Arabic locales, for
>   example. This number localization occurs for the decimal integer
>   conversion %d, the floating point conversions %e, %f, and %g, and all
>   date/time %t or %T conversions, but no other conversions.

Btw ٠١ means 01 in arabic numbers. So I'll replace my calls to

```
String.format(Locale.US, "level_end:%02d:win", level)
```

and will see does it help.